# Create procedure with if in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to create a procedure that search an email in a table, and if it doesn´t exists the procedure creates a new record with this email.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_email (in @email varchar2(99)) AS

BEGIN
 IF SELECT email FROM user u WHERE u.email:=email
 
     dbms_output.put_line('This email exists');
    
 ELSE 
 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO user (id, name, surname, city, address, age, email) VALUES (id_user.nextval,'David','Alcatraz','Sevilla', 'Avd miguel de unamuno', 23, email || '@gmail.com')
    END
```

Comment: You can first query SELECT count(1) into v_count FROM user u WHERE u.email:=email and  if v_count  > 0 then dbms_output.put_line('This email exists'); else existing code

Comment: What is the problem here ? You are quite clear about your requirement and what stops you doing it ? Could you tell about the problem you are facing?

Comment: There needs to be an `end` for every `begin` and an `end if` for every `if`. The `@` character is reserved for database links. Every row in the `email` table will have `email = email`, surely.

Answer (score 0):

Take this in consideration:

- A variable to store the counter of email from the table.
- You must close each statement with semicolon.
- An input variable is defined with its type without length.

It would look like

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE check_email (p_email in varchar2 ) AS
    v_counter pls_integer;
    BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) into v_counter FROM user WHERE upper(email) = upper(p_email);
     if v_counter = 1 
     then
         dbms_output.put_line('This email exists');
     ELSE 
         INSERT INTO user (id, name, surname, city, address, age, email) VALUES 
      (id_user.nextval,'David','Alcatraz','Sevilla', 'Avd miguel de unamuno', 23, p_email || 
     '@gmail.com');
         commit;
     END IF;
    exception when others then raise;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother? Let the database handle that.

Here's how: as e-mail addresses have to be unique, create a *unique key constraint* on that column:

```
SQL> create table t_user
  2    (id       number constraint pk_user primary key,
  3     name     varchar2(20) not null,
  4     e_mail   varchar2(30) not null,
  5              --
  6              constraint uk_user_mail unique (e_mail)
  7    );

Table created.
```

Sequence will be used for the `ID` column values.

```
SQL> create sequence tseq;

Sequence created.
```

Procedure: if there's unique key violation, simply don't do anything. Other errors, if any, will be automatically raised by Oracle. You can handle them, if you want.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_user
  2    (par_name  in t_user.name%type,
  3     par_email in t_user.e_mail%type)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    insert into t_user (id, name, e_mail)
  7      values (tseq.nextval, par_name, par_email);
  8  exception
  9    when dup_val_on_index then null;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_user('Little', 'lf@mail.com');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_user('Foot'  , 'lf@mail.com');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_user('Victor', 'victor@mail.com');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From t_user;

        ID NAME                 E_MAIL
---------- -------------------- ------------------------------
         1 Little               lf@mail.com
         3 Victor               victor@mail.com

SQL>
```

As you can see, *Foot* never entered the table as its e-mail address already exists in the table.